# How to typeset long equation in journal papers

Tags: matrices

I am writing a journal and my matrix is too long to be contained in one column.
Please, what is the best way to typeset the matrix?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
$$
A_c & = \begin{bmatrix}
       I_N \otimes AT &  I_N \otimes B CD & I_N \otimes B(t)B(t)C(t) \\
        0 & AAA -\alpha_1 DDD  & 0 \\
        -I_N \otimes CC & I_N \otimes A(t)A(t) + E + \gamma ) & I_N \otimes (A(t) + B(t) + C(t))
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's absolutely essential to show all 9 elements of the matrix `A_c`, you could display them as three column vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,lipsum}
\begin{document}

%\[
%A_c = \begin{bmatrix}
%       I_N \otimes AT &  I_N \otimes B CD & I_N \otimes B(t)B(t)C(t) \\
%        0 & AAA -\alpha_1 DDD  & 0 \\
%        -I_N \otimes CC & I_N \otimes A(t)A(t) + E + \gamma ) & I_N \otimes (A(t) + B(t) + C(t))
%    \end{bmatrix}
%\]

\noindent
Let
\[
A_c = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \end{bmatrix} \,,
\]
where
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
       I_N \otimes AT \\
        0 \\
        -I_N \otimes CC 
\end{bmatrix} \\[\jot]
a_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}
       I_N \otimes B CD \\
        AAA -\alpha_1 DDD  \\
        I_N \otimes A(t)A(t) + E + \gamma ) 
\end{bmatrix} \\[\jot]
a_3 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
       I_N \otimes B(t)B(t)C(t) \\
        0 \\
        I_N \otimes (A(t) + B(t) + C(t))
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice approach. You follow two inventive principles: do a little less, and separate in space.